# Google's Geocoding Restrictions - can I store the result?

Tags: api, google-maps

Google's terms state that:

the Geocoding API may only be used in conjunction with a Google map; geocoding results without displaying them on a map is prohibited.

Can I geocode an address and store the results in a database, with the sole purpose of displaying it on a google map at a future point? Or is storing these naked co-ordinates completely prohibited?

Process would be that one application uses the API to geocode a location and write the lattitude/longitude to a database. Later, a website displays a google map using that stored data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are allowed to "cache" them in your database.  You are requested to periodically refresh the values.  See this ["article" in the documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/geocodestrat#caching)